# Exporting/publishing a C++ program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, publish

I have made a simple game in VS 2012 using C++, and I am just wondering if it is possible to "export" or "publish" the project so that is possible to use using a single .exe anywhere on a computer, rather than the whole debug folder that includes all the pictures I have used.

Many thanks!

Comment: As a start, switch the build from "debug" to "release", and be sure you use static linking to necessary libraries.

Comment: Try right-clicking on your solution and choosing "Other Project Types" -> "Setup and Deployment."

Comment: when I right click there isnt any option for other project types